# Where to lookup the windows phone application GUID

Tags: windows-phone-7, guid

Tools in Windows Phone SDK (like Isolated Storage Explorer) require passing an application's GUID as one of the command line parameters to  operate on a particular application either on a real device or an emulator. So far I have been able to lookup the application GUID for Windows Phone application through an IsolatedStorage `OpenFile` method. The application's GUID for Windows Phone application is not the same as the GUID in the Assembly information dialog in the properties of the project in Visual Studio.

So how does one lookup the application's GUID in Windows Phone project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your windows phone project folder, go to properties folder and there you will find WPAppManifest.xml file. It contains ProductID which is the app GUID.